# Microsoft Edge keeps resetting printing setting to "one side"

Tags: printing, microsoft-edge, duplex

**tl;dr** *Edge keeps changing printing settings to "one side" even though I have "both sides" sets at system level. Is there anything I can do to force it to "remember" this setting?*

---

I have "both sides" setting enforced at the Windows 11 / printer driver level:

[image]

Yet, Microsoft Edge keeps ignoring this fact and keeps switching this setting to "one side":

[image]

Each time I see that "it" has "reset" it back to "one side", I change it back to "both sides". Only to find out within next few days that thi setting is again "reset" to "one side".

I have this problem with Microsoft Edge only. Each and every other application or system component that I use strictly follows system-level settings. Therefore, my question is (since this is Edge-specific), is this some kind of a bug (reported somewhere or must I report it?) or maybe someone at Microsoft is trying to be more clever than me?

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

Edge remembers printing settings for any common printer.

I use Edge with an HP Printer on two computers and settings are remembered.

Check some things:

1. Turn Edge Sync OFF.  If you want it on make sure printing is set up on all computers.
2. Repair Edge. Start, Settings, Apps, and scroll down for Edge. Select Modify and choose Repair.   (Edge, not Edge Update).
3. Run DISM / SFC

   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
   (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
   (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
   (4) SFC /SCANNOW
4. After all the above is complete, restart and test.

This should do it.  If not you will be looking more aggressive repairs.